# At first I insert null in TreeSet. After that I insert any other value why it gives NPE?

Tags: java, collections, treeset

```
 public static void main(String []args){
    TreeSet tree = new TreeSet();
    String obj = "Ranga";
    tree.add(null);
    tree.add(obj);
 }
```

As per my knowledge, the TreeSet is depends on default natural sorting order. So JVM internally calls compareTo() method.

In above example, the case is:

> obj.compareTo(null);

So, **why the result is null pointer exception?**

Comment: In our normal case if we have code null.method(obj); So we will get null pointer exception. but if we have obj.method(null); we do not get null pointer exception.                                                                                               So why the case of compareTo() is different than other.

Comment: Doesn’t the NPE get thrown by the first add?

Comment: @cppbeginner No. If TreeSet is empty it allows null insertion. But after adding null if I add anything it gives NPE

Comment: It depends what version you use. In Java 8 you get an exception on the first add (I just tried it). Even with the old version of TreeSet, the fact that it’s obj.compareTo(null) is not relevant as this throws an NPE anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From 1.7 onwards null is not at all accepted by TreeSet. If you enforce to add then we will get NullPointerException. Till 1.6 null was accepted only as the first element.

Before java 7 -

For a non-empty TreeSet, if we are trying to insert a null value at run time you will get a NullPointerException. This is because when some elements exist in the tree, before inserting any object it compares the new object to the existing ones using the compareTo() method and decides where to put the new object. So by inserting null the compareTo() method internally throws NullPointerException.

[TreeMap Add method documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#add%28E%29)

When you try to add null on empty TreeSet initially it does not contain any element to compare hence its add without NPE, when second element you will add in TreeSet, TreeSet will use Comparable compareTo() method to sort the element and place into TreeSet object hence it will call null.compareTo() which defiantly leads to NPE.

TreeSet backed by TreeMap internally, before java 7 TreeMap put(K,V) doesn't have null check for K(key) and from java 7 null check has been added in TreeMap put(K.V) mehod

Before java 7 TreeMap put mehod code does not have null check -

```
  public V put(K key, V value) {
        Entry<K,V> t = root;

        if (t == null) {
            incrementSize();
            root = new Entry<K,V>(key, value, null);
            return null;
       }

        while (true) {
            int cmp = compare(key, t.key);
            if (cmp == 0) {
                return t.setValue(value);
            } else if (cmp < 0) {
                if (t.left != null) {
                    t = t.left;
                } else {
                    incrementSize();
                    t.left = new Entry<K,V>(key, value, t);
                    fixAfterInsertion(t.left);
                    return null;
                }
            } else { // cmp > 0
                if (t.right != null) {
                    t = t.right;
                } else {
                    incrementSize();
                    t.right = new Entry<K,V>(key, value, t);
                    fixAfterInsertion(t.right);
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

from java 7  you can see null check for key, if its is null it will throw NPE.

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
    Entry<K,V> t = root;
    if (t == null) {
        compare(key, key); // type (and possibly null) check

        root = new Entry<>(key, value, null);
        size = 1;
        modCount++;
        return null;
    }
    int cmp;
    Entry<K,V> parent;
    // split comparator and comparable paths
    Comparator<? super K> cpr = comparator;
    if (cpr != null) {
        do {
            parent = t;
            cmp = cpr.compare(key, t.key);
            if (cmp < 0)
                t = t.left;
            else if (cmp > 0)
                t = t.right;
            else
                return t.setValue(value);
        } while (t != null);
    }
    else {
        if (key == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        Comparable<? super K> k = (Comparable<? super K>) key;
        do {
            parent = t;
            cmp = k.compareTo(t.key);
            if (cmp < 0)
                t = t.left;
            else if (cmp > 0)
                t = t.right;
            else
                return t.setValue(value);
        } while (t != null);
    }
    Entry<K,V> e = new Entry<>(key, value, parent);
    if (cmp < 0)
        parent.left = e;
    else
        parent.right = e;
    fixAfterInsertion(e);
    size++;
    modCount++;
    return null;
}
```

I hope this will leads you on proper conclusion.

Comment: The question is why it should throw NPE.

Comment: Just wanted to know what is that internal implementation?

Answer (score 0):

In "relatively recent" Java versions (from the 6th version), the `NullPointerException`  is expected to be thrown in the first `add()` invocation :

```
tree.add(null);
```

as [`TreeSet.add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#add-E-) javadoc states that :

> **throw NullPointerException** -
>    if the specified element is null and this set uses natural ordering,
>   or its comparator does not permit null elements

Note that it is specified in this way from [the JDK 6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#add(E)).
For example [JDK 5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#add(E)) doesn't explicit this point.

If you use an old Java version (as Java 5), please specify it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, don't use raw types instead utilise the power of generics:

```
TreeSet<String> tree = new TreeSet<>();
```

As for your issue:

`TreeSet` no longer supports the addition of `null`.

From the doc:

> `public boolean add(E e)`
>
> Throws `NullPointerException` if the specified element is null and this set
>   uses natural ordering,  or its comparator does not permit null
>   elements.

solutions to overcome this issue:

Provide a null-safe comparator where the `null` elements will come first:

```
TreeSet<String> tree = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```

or provide a null-safe comparator where the `null` elements will come last:

```
TreeSet<String> tree = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to maintain the contract and the behavior is enforced by[Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) incase of natural ordering.

> The natural ordering for a class C is said to be consistent with equals if and only if e1.compareTo(e2) == 0 has the same boolean value as e1.equals(e2) for every e1 and e2 of class C. **Note that null is not an instance of any class, and e.compareTo(null) should throw a NullPointerException even though e.equals(null) returns false.**

Comment: You mean to say that behavior is enforced by the comparable interface?

Comment: Enforce I mean, by it's specification.